# ObjectAid UML Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, objectaid

I'm trying to install the ObjectAid software for *Eclipse Luna 4.4*.

**Eclipse Environment:**

- JDK Compliance 1.8
- Installed JREs: jre1.8.0_60

**System Environment:**

- Java 1.8.0_60

After installing the current release 1.2 (http://www.objectaid.com/update/current) and restarting Eclipse when I try to add a diagram (
*File > New > ObjectAid UML Diagram >  Class Diagram*) I get the following error:

```
The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in com.objectaid.uml.cls was unable to load class com.objectaid.uml.cls.editor.NewClassDiagramWizard.
com/objectaid/uml/cls/editor/NewClassDiagramWizard : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I know this happens because there's a mismatch between java version used at compile time vs run time.

I don't see the mismatch though since I'm using Java 8 everywhere. I found the full error log that ObjectAid creates and it starts like this:

```
!SESSION 2017-05-31 14:41:08.722 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.7.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```

Now the question is where is picking up 1.7 from? And how do I change this?

(Note that Java 7 is indeed installed on my machine but it's not set as a default anywhere and it's not even in the path.)

A friend has the same config and everything works for him but he's using *Eclipse Neon 4.6.3*.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDK 7 may be referenced from the 'eclipse.ini' configuration file in your Eclipse directory.

Comment: I checked and java there was -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6! I haven't tested it to be honest because I upgraded to Neon after all but it looks like that was the issue. Thanks Felix !

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had changed everywhere to 1.8 and even maven was showing it building with 1.8. Problem was exact what you mentioned in your answer, eclipse.ini was referring 1.7 :P

Comment: The following argument in eclipse.ini is what needs to be changed  
-vm D:/installs/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin
I have left the following argument as before and it works
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6