# ObjectAid issue with version

Tags: eclipse, objectaid

Eclipse Kepler Environment:
    JDK Compliance 1.6
    Installed JREs: jre1.6

System Environment:
    Java 1.6

I am using all the versions which should be suitable for ObjectAid, but I am still getting below error.

Error:
The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in com.objectaid.uml.cls was unable to load class com.objectaid.uml.cls.editor.NewClassDiagramWizard.
com/objectaid/uml/cls/editor/NewClassDiagramWizard : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Can anybody help on this please?
Thanks!

Comment: see similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290327/objectaid-uml-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0/44291141#44291141

Comment: Configuration settings in eclipse.ini is also pointing to 1.6

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates you have installed ObjectAid 1.2 which requires JDK 8.
ObjectAid 1.1 still runs on JDK 6.